# "Sudo certbot --nginx" failed to run, its related to "configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed"

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, certbot

I got this error code when i tried to run "sudo certbot --nginx"

<<
Error while running nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t.

nginx: [emerg] dlopen() "/opt/bitnami/nginx/modules/ngx_http_auth_pam_module.so" failed (/opt/bitnami/nginx/modules/ngx_http_auth_pam_module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-auth-pam.conf:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

> > 

only major issue during install was i locked the front end when i tried to see the difference in two softwares; after several delete and reinstall attempts, nginx is running with no errors, sudo nginx -t returns a successful propt etc.

how the heck do i fix this?

after reinstalling everything multiple times; i expected the software to work; previous i was getting an exit error in the dpkg file but reinstalling nginx completely fixed that and lead to the current error.

Note - running restart, status and stop etc for nginx "sudo service nginx restart" etc all run successfully, i only get this error while trying to run certbot

Note 2 - the website is actually down now; while i was getting the error for status it was still up; i did run "sudo fuser -k 443/tcp" and "sudo fuser -k 80/tcp" in order to reinstall nginx.

Note 3 - currently website just displays the "welcome to nginx" page it also displayed welcome to apache but it swapped after i removed apache.

Note 4 - im an engineer not a coder. so if you say add "xx" line to a file, tell me how to open and save the file too